# Hadoop Streaming on AWS submits no job, silently fails - are there logs?

Tags: logging, hadoop, amazon-web-services, hadoop-streaming

Even a very basic Hadoop Streaming job submitted from my AWS edge node:

```
hadoop jar /usr/share/hadoop/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-1.0.4.jar \
-D mapred.job.name=MarksClusterTest \
-file /mnt/home/mpundurs/Clustering/passthrough.py \
-mapper /mnt/home/mpundurs/Clustering/passthrough.py \
-file /mnt/home/mpundurs/Clustering/passthrough.py \
-reducer /mnt/home/mpundurs/Clustering/passthrough.py \
-input /user/mpundurs/Clustering/input.csv \
-output /user/mpundurs/Clustering/output
```

sends only the following to my screen before returning me to the command prompt:

```
packageJobJar: [/mnt/home/mpundurs/Clustering/passthrough.py, 
/mnt/home/mpundurs/Clustering/passthrough.py, 
/mnt/tmp/hadoop-mpundurs/hadoop-unjar523304178423152265/] []
/tmp/streamjob8344547788966317309.jar tmpDir=null
```

There is no record on http://*HeadNodeIP*:9100/jobtracker.jsp of any map-reduce job having been submitted.

Does Hadoop Streaming itself - rather than the job it submits (or doesn't) - create a log? If so, where?

Comment: What is the difference between your mapper and reducer? Are you using same file for both map and reduce tasks?

Comment: I am using the same file for the purpose of ruling out as many causes of failure as possible.